# Conditional validation on Custom form request

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5

on my controller I have:

```
 public function store(ProductRequest $request)
```

The request:

```
class ProductRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'perTypeTime' => 'sometimes|required',
            'per_type_id' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to change the perTypeTime rule above to be conditional depending on if per_type_id field == 1.

If I initiated the validator in the controller I believe I could do something like the below:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'per_type_id' => 'required|email'
]);

$v->sometimes('perTypeTime', 'required|max:500', function($input)
{
    return $input->per_type_id == 1;
});
```

Is there a way to do this, while keeping my custom request. I like how this approach keeps the controller cleaner.

I can't seem to access the validator on the request object. Is there a way to specify this condition inside the request itself, or to access the validator from the request object, or is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that

> I want to change the perTypeTime rule above to be conditional depending on if per_type_id field == 1.

within your `rules()` method in your `ProductRequest`.
For details see **required_if:anotherfield,value** in the [Laravel documentation validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-if).

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'          => 'required|min:3',
        'perTypeTime'   => 'required_if:per_type_id,1',
        'per_type_id'   => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: This method is fine for this specific use case but it doesn't solve the root of the problem: What to do if I have a very special validation only relevant for my business like `userIsAGoat()`?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.3, in your request file you can add:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;
```

...

```
public function validator(Factory $factory)
{
    $validator = $factory->make($this->input(), $this->rules());
    $validator->sometimes('your_sometimes_field', 'your_validation_rule', function($input) {
        return $input->your_sometimes_field !== null;
    });
    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: Overriding validator function. This is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: This solution is available since [Laravel 5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L75), so it applies also for versions previous to 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41842050/3922975 is not the best.
We don't have to replace default validator with our own (because we are not changing anything). In that solution we hope validation factory will always require only two attributes ($this->input(), $this->rules()) which is actually not true even in time of writing.

This is a default validator used by Laravel:

```
$factory->make(
    $this->validationData(), 
    $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']),
    $this->messages(), 
    $this->attributes()
);
```

As you can see it is much different from that Artem Verbo used.

Better solution is to create withValidator method in your ProductRequest class:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
```

...

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->sometimes('your_sometimes_field', 'your_validation_rule', function ($input) {
        return $input->your_sometimes_field !== null;
    });
}
```